# Adding nguniversal/express-engine to Angular proj: "Cannot find BrowserModule import in /src/app/app.module.ts"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular-universal

First question

### Goal

I'm trying to add SSR to my Angular project with `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [name]` (so I can dynamically prerender meta tags)

### Expected Result

I expected the command to execute successfully with all the scaffolding and necessary updates to my existing files, as demonstrated in this YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VDOAjzLcvQ).

### Actual Result

Instead, the console says this:

```
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Cannot find BrowserModule import in /src/app/app.module.ts
```

But BrowserModule **is** imported in app.module.ts.

### What I've Tried

1. Reinstalling package

I've tried uninstalling the package with `npm uninstall @nguniversal/express-engine`and re-running the `ng add` above, same issue.

Other posted questions about ng adding @nguniversal/express-server don't seem to apply here, as those guys actually got as far as creating some of the scaffolding and generating the new files - no files are created for me at all, but the module does get added to my node-modules folder.

Could it be an issue with simply reading the typescript in app.module.ts? The BrowserModule import is there, and in the imports array. This is the output for `npm ls typescript`:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.8
| `-- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.901.8
|   `-- typescript@3.6.5
+-- @ng-toolkit/universal@1.1.21
| +-- @ng-toolkit/_utils@1.1.51
| | `-- @schematics/angular@7.3.10
| |   `-- typescript@3.2.4
| `-- @schematics/angular@0.6.8
|   `-- typescript@2.7.2
`-- typescript@3.8.3
```

### Additional Info (for David)

1. app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule, Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
    import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
    import { SoftwareComponent } from './software/software.component';
    import { MediaComponent } from './media/media.component';
    import { ShopComponent } from './shop/shop.component';
    import { FilmDetailsComponent } from './film-details/film-details.component';
    import { ShareModalComponent } from './share-modal/share-modal.component';
    import { ShareModule } from 'ngx-sharebuttons';
    import { ShareButtonModule } from 'ngx-sharebuttons/button';
    import { ShareIconsModule } from 'ngx-sharebuttons/icons';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ShareButtonModule,
        ShareIconsModule // Optional if you want the default share icons
      ]
    })
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        SoftwareComponent,
        MediaComponent,
        ShopComponent,
        FilmDetailsComponent,
        ShareModalComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        ShareModule,
        ShareButtonModule,
        ShareIconsModule
      ],
      providers: [Meta, Title],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

2. main.ts

```
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    
    import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
    import { environment } from './environments/environment';
    
    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }
    
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Can you show your `app.module.ts` and `main.ts` files?

Comment: @David  - cheers for showing interest, I've updated the question with those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by multiple NgModules in the app.module, as the first NgModule imports doesn't contain BrowserModule.

app would still work fine if you remove first NgModule since the modules in the imports are already imported in the second one

Comment: You legend, thank you! That was it. I never would have spotted that on my own, but now it seems obvious. Hero!

Comment: Glad it helped!  :)